# dynamic background images of different dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div of 100pxx100px and would like to load dynamically background images within it.
These images are of all different sizes and I would like that they fit within the div without being distorted.

It appears that background-size: contain; works well but is only supported by modern browsers (as usual IE being the real bugger...)

Could someone please recommend a solution to this as I am out of ideas?
Anny help appreciated.

Comment: Load `<img>` inside the `div`. ..and you can make `<img>` work much like css background if that is what you need..

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do not use the `100x100 div` as a background image container. You should add a `img` tag or another div inside the `100x100 div` to use as the image container.

Then, write a simple algorithm to find out the orientation of the image and how to best fit the image container into the `100x100 div` and set the image container's `height` and `width` to scale. Then center it vertically and horizontally inside the `100x100 div`.

I threw together an example in jsfiddle.

[Tall Image and Wide Image Scaled using JS](http://jsfiddle.net/XRXQe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Typical IE. You can do this with a filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='YOUR_IMAGE', sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='YOUR_IMAGE',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```